# What is the correct English word for "so much high"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

> While mixing Hot Tea with sugar, We take two glasses, we pour Hot Tea in one
>   glass & put sugar in other one. we mix them by pouring Hot Tea to another
>   glass with **so much high**. But be careful, Hot Tea may spill on your hand with this
>   heights.

This is the sentence I phrase about tea making, But still people feel difficulty in understand because of words "**so much high**". I need help to replace this three words with single word or more appropriate English words with same meaning.

I am describing tea that must be poured from a some height, which will have enough chances to get spill on the hand.

Comment: **One glass is held high above the other when pouring** is what I am expecting. Thank you! you answered my question through comments.

Comment: I expect "so much" means "this much" in this case ("Oh, he's about so high"). So perhaps "from this height" or something similar. But I'm not sure why the height would have to be specified at all. And if it's milk that's being poured, I suppose the tea that might get on your hand results from splashing?...

Comment: @LukeSawczak When making tea, some folks pour the water and steeped tea back and forth between two glasses. Think of a talented bartender doing what they call a "long pull" or "high pour".

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ah, okay. And I guess the height is for extra showmanship?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It may also oxygenate the liquid in some wise. But for sure, there's an element of theatre in it.

Comment: @user33250 Given the above, I think we still need you to clarify your meaning. Are you describing tea that must be poured from a certain, **specific** height? Or are you saying the tea must be poured from a **great** height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to find a perfect fit.

> You could say, "We pour, from an exaggerated height, the hot tea into the glass with the sugar."

Exaggerated height in this case would simply mean a height greater than one would expect necessary to simply transfer liquid between two glasses.

Answer (score 1):

One glass is held high above the other when pouring. -- from comments

You should also try to fix other errors, in capitalisation for example. You don't need to repeat "hot". Once you have established that the tea is hot you don't need the adjective. The final part "with this heights" is not needed. There is also an odd change in tone. It starts descriptive, then switches to giving advice